# Using the Router to change web page on form submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, components, router

I am trying to change to the render of a component called `Party`
when the form is submitted from component `Events`.

This is the render method for the `Events` Component:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <h3> Create Event </h3>
                    {this.createUser()}
                    <div>
                        <input type="button" value="add more" onClick={this.addClick.bind(this)} />
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                </form>

                <div>
                    <Link to="/party">Party</Link>
                    <Route path="/party" component={Party} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

and the render for the `Party` Component is something simple like:

```
class Party extends Component {
    render() {
        return <h1> PARTY </h1>;
    }
}
```

The page changed to `/party`, but the form still stays on the page and doesn't disappear. I just started React so I am a complete noob.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The form always be present because you always render it.
In order to display the form in a particular path, and the `Party` component in another one you should use the `react-router` [Switch](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md) component

> Renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location.

Possible scenario:

```
<Router>
    <div>
        <div>
            <Link to="/">Form</Link>
            <Link to="/party">Party</Link>
        </div>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Form} />
            <Route path="/party" component={Party} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
</Router>
```

Where the `Form` component has your `<form></form>` and is displayed only when the url is `/`.

I think this [react-seed](https://github.com/UruIT/react-seed) project could be helpful for you.